# I'm using a for loop to add an event listener to a bunch of different buttons, but how do I make sure each button only affects to a specific div?

Tags: javascript, html

Creating a simple "workout builder" where there's a list of exercises in one column with their own descriptions, sample videos, and "add button". When the "add button" is clicked, that specific exercise is moved over to another column. I could obviously give each add button its own ID and hardcode each thing, but I'm trying to do it a bit more elegantly.

I'm trying to write it as a for loop, where each button gets assigned its own event listener. But then, how do I make sure each button only affects a specific div? I'm using querySelectorAll, which I know also creates an array, but how do I make sure that addButton[1] only affects exercise[1] or addButton[45] only affects exercise [45] and so on and so forth.

HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="header-title">WORKOUT BUILDER</h1>
            <img id="header-img" src="img/workoutheader.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- This is the big list of exercises.     -->
        <div class="list-of-exercises">     
            <!-- This is an individual exercise. -->
                <div class="exercise" id="power-clean">
                    <div class="exercise-name">
                    <h2 class="name" id="power-clean-name">Power Clean</h2>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Here's the add button for this specific exercise. As you can see I have a specific ID here where I could hardcore each button, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. -->
                    <button class="add-button" id="add-button-power-clean">Add</button>
                    <!-- This is the rest of the exercise content, like a sample GIF, sets and reps, etc. -->
                    <div class="exercise-contents" id="power-clean-contents">   
                    <iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/c10FJ0dpZ5CEF03JTO" width="480" height="270" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/crossfit-power-clean-lift-c10FJ0dpZ5CEF03JTO"></a></p>
                    <div class="sets-and-reps-form" id="sets-and-reps-form-power-clean">
                    <label for="sets">Sets</label>
                    <input type="number" class="sets" id="sets-power-clean" fname="sets"> 
                    <br>
                    <label for="reps">Reps</label>
                    <input type="number" class="reps" id="reps-power-clean" fname="reps"> 
                    <input class="sets-and-reps-submit" id="sets-and-reps-submit-power-clean" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Here's the start of the next exercise. -->
                <div class="exercise" id="back-squat">
                    <div class="exercise-name">
                    <h2 class="name" id="back-squat-name">Back Squat</h2>
                    </div>
                    <button class="add-button" id="add-button-back-squat">Add</button>
                    <div class="exercise-contents" id="back-squat-contents">
                    <div class="tenor-gif-embed" data-postid="24035556" data-share-method="host" data-aspect-ratio="1.49533" data-width="100%"><a href="https://tenor.com/view/workouts-squats-gif-24035556">Workouts Squats GIF</a>from <a href="https://tenor.com/search/workouts-gifs">Workouts GIFs</a></div> <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://tenor.com/embed.js"></script>
                    <div class="sets-and-reps-form" id="sets-and-reps-form-back-squat">
                        <label for="sets">Sets</label>
                        <input type="number" class="sets" id="sets-back-squat" fname="sets"> 
                        <br>
                        <label for="reps">Reps</label>
                        <input type="number" class="reps" id="reps-back-squat" fname="reps"> 
                        <input class="sets-and-reps-submit" id="sets-and-reps-submit-back-squat" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- This is the div where I want people to be able to "add" the different exercises. -->
        <div class="exercise-builder">
            <div class="final-readout">
            <p id="intensity-score">Intensity Score: 0</p>
            <p id="ETA">Estimated Time To Complete Workout: 0</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
```

Javascript

```
let moveToBuilder = function(){
    let exerciseBuilder = document.querySelector(".exercise-builder");
    let exercise = document.querySelectorAll(".exercise");
    // So here I'm just using 0 as the array test value to get it working. But like how could I turn the 0 into something that pairs with the various Submit Button array values? So when I hit the "Power Clean" add button, it only adds Power Clean, etc.
    exerciseBuilder.insertBefore(exercise[0], exerciseBuilder.firstChild);
    } 

for (var i = 0; i < addButton.length; i++) {
    addButton[i].addEventListener('click', moveToBuilder, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your JavaScript with a few tweaks. I've:

- Added a little array `exercises` to allow the needed text to be picked up by index, which in turn is used to find the correct elements;
- Used `document.getElementById()` twice to cleanly pick up elements by id (this is more robust in general that the `querySelectorAll()`: one weakness of that is that the numbering of the elements changes when they are re-ordered on the page;
- Perhaps most importantly, I've added an arrow function to the event listener, which returns a different invocation of `moveToBuilder()` depending on the value of `i`. This effectively puts different event listeners on the different buttons, as you wanted; and
- To make this work, the scope of the variable `i` had to be limited with a `let` declaration rather than `var` otherwise `i` = 2 at all material times (after the loop has finished).

```js
let exercises = ["power-clean", "back-squat"]

let moveToBuilder = function(index){
    let exerciseBuilder = document.querySelector(".exercise-builder");
    let exercise = document.getElementById(exercises[index]);
    // So here I'm just using 0 as the array test value to get it working. But like how could I turn the 0 into something that pairs with the various Submit Button array values? So when I hit the "Power Clean" add button, it only adds Power Clean, etc.
    exerciseBuilder.appendChild(exercise);
} 

for (let i = 0; i < exercises.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(`add-button-${exercises[i]}`).addEventListener('click', () => moveToBuilder(i), false);
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="header-title">WORKOUT BUILDER</h1>
            <img id="header-img" src="img/workoutheader.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- This is the big list of exercises.     -->
        <div class="list-of-exercises">     
            <!-- This is an individual exercise. -->
                <div class="exercise" id="power-clean">
                    <div class="exercise-name">
                    <h2 class="name" id="power-clean-name">Power Clean</h2>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Here's the add button for this specific exercise. As you can see I have a specific ID here where I could hardcore each button, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. -->
                    <button class="add-button" id="add-button-power-clean">Add</button>
                    <!-- This is the rest of the exercise content, like a sample GIF, sets and reps, etc. -->
                    <div class="exercise-contents" id="power-clean-contents">   
                    <iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/c10FJ0dpZ5CEF03JTO" width="480" height="270" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/crossfit-power-clean-lift-c10FJ0dpZ5CEF03JTO"></a></p>
                    <div class="sets-and-reps-form" id="sets-and-reps-form-power-clean">
                    <label for="sets">Sets</label>
                    <input type="number" class="sets" id="sets-power-clean" fname="sets"> 
                    <br>
                    <label for="reps">Reps</label>
                    <input type="number" class="reps" id="reps-power-clean" fname="reps"> 
                    <input class="sets-and-reps-submit" id="sets-and-reps-submit-power-clean" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Here's the start of the next exercise. -->
                <div class="exercise" id="back-squat">
                    <div class="exercise-name">
                    <h2 class="name" id="back-squat-name">Back Squat</h2>
                    </div>
                    <button class="add-button" id="add-button-back-squat">Add</button>
                    <div class="exercise-contents" id="back-squat-contents">
                    <div class="tenor-gif-embed" data-postid="24035556" data-share-method="host" data-aspect-ratio="1.49533" data-width="100%"><a href="https://tenor.com/view/workouts-squats-gif-24035556">Workouts Squats GIF</a>from <a href="https://tenor.com/search/workouts-gifs">Workouts GIFs</a></div> <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://tenor.com/embed.js"></script>
                    <div class="sets-and-reps-form" id="sets-and-reps-form-back-squat">
                        <label for="sets">Sets</label>
                        <input type="number" class="sets" id="sets-back-squat" fname="sets"> 
                        <br>
                        <label for="reps">Reps</label>
                        <input type="number" class="reps" id="reps-back-squat" fname="reps"> 
                        <input class="sets-and-reps-submit" id="sets-and-reps-submit-back-squat" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- This is the div where I want people to be able to "add" the different exercises. -->
        <div class="exercise-builder">
            <div class="final-readout">
            <p id="intensity-score">Intensity Score: 0</p>
            <p id="ETA">Estimated Time To Complete Workout: 0</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is a great help, much appreciated!